# Should I use dummy variables or just assign numerical values to categorical predictors in regression / PCA?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, pca, data-mining

When wanting to apply PCA or Linear Regression on some data set, I understand that the explanatory variables (features) should have numerical values.

My current situation is that out of 79, I have 43 Factorial variables, which I intend to transform.

1. 1st Option - Is to convert each factorial variable to X dummy variables. which gives a lot more features, of course.
2. 2nd Option - Is to assign numerical value to each factor level, without order relevance, e.g. convert feature that gets the following levels: `{"Interior", "Exterior"}`, to get the following levels: `{0, 1}`

What do I need to consider before using each of the options?

Or, how to determine which option serves me best \ determine if that's the correct approach?

My end goal is to predict continuous variable using the explanatory variables (If that's something to consider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, where the variable has only two levels, the two approaches are the same. When there are more than two levels, you will usually (almost always) want dummy variables because there will not be a sensible numerical coding of the levels.  And you don't need to code it yourself; every decent statistical package (R, SAS, SPSS etc) will do it for you; most offer a few choices on how to do it (dummy coding, effect coding, Helmert coding).

Comment: I do have lots of variable with approx. 4-5 levels.
Regarding sensible numerical coding - if for example i code 
`Feature X = { "A", "B", "C", "D" }` to `Feature X = {0, 1, 2, 3}` and specify that X values are unordered ones, why use 5 dummy variables instead of just one with 4 numerical values, which have no 'greater than' or `smaller than` significance?
I don't quite get it, if you could elaborate a bit please :)
Thanks

Comment: @Adiel How can you "specify that X values are unordered ones"?

Comment: @amoeba I Guess you're right :) I got confused by old piece of code I wrote `factor(cut(data$colName, 4, ordered=TRUE))` in order to discretize some continuous features in a data set. Thanks!